# How to Integrate SpagoBI server in Grails or Java application

Tags: java, grails, spagobi

I want to Integrate **SpagoBI** server in Grails or Java applications. I have developed some report in SpagoBI server and it is working fine. The same reports I want to display in Grails or Java applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SpagoBI SDK to integrate it in your web application (especially Java). Take a look here: http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_sdk/

Answer (score 0):

The SpagoBI SDK download contains examples of using the JavaScript tag library and Java libraries for retrieving available reports, executing, and displaying the report

You can also see a code sample I posted previously at the link below. It uses JSP and the SpagoBI Java library to execute a specified report (by label) and return a PDF or XLS.

http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/3592.page